# Search has an extra border in the topbar

Tags: bug, status-planned, search, top-bar

As seen in the screenshot, there is an extra border over the search icon on the topbar. This started today, coincedentally with the start of Winter Bash, but not caused by it as confirmed by staff.

[image]

Running Chrome on Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug!

This issue is related to a [CSS refactor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/6550e1529412c2edac3fc10f683cb74e56957e38) performed on our button component that shipped out early this morning and is unrelated to winter bash. A slightly transparent, white inner box-shadow is being applied to our `primary`, `danger`, and `muted` variant styles in light mode.

We're currently under a code freeze until January 2nd, so a fix for this won't go live until the first week of January. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: So this isn't related to winter bash if I understand correctly? You guys sure enjoy a long holiday season with such a code freeze.

Comment: Correct, this bug is unrelated to winter bash. I'll update my comment to make that clearer. As for the holiday season, we take the last week of the year off but many staff members opt to prepend some vacation time to that break. To ensure we can all relax and avoid firefighting while people are away, we introduce the code freeze well before the official holiday break.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Dan, I edited the tags on the question itself accordingly.